# Firebase query returning null despite exact match

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For simplicities sake I'm including a screenshot of the query to firebase along with the structure. The query is manually made to match the database here for troubleshooting purposes.

As you can see, they match, however it always returns null, and I can't figure out why. IS there a problem I'm over loocking? Or am I just fundamentally misunderstanding the query structure for firebase?

[image: Link to image on imgur because I'm new]

```
Firebase.database().ref("checkins/7hsGDNvT8IfbVSsWcmrS7vMVVXP2").orderByChild("guid")
            .equalTo('ChIJ2bg3MkVZVFMR6cV20WHTfEo').once("value", snapshot => {
            const userData = snapshot.val();
            console.log(userData);
        });
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image given, it seems that you're missing a character at the end of the `guid` property.

"ChIJ2bg3MkVZVFMR6cV20WHTfEo[?]"

If you look closely, you'll notice that you can't see the end of the value as the closing doble quotes are not showing.

[image]

Please click on the value of that property so you can see the complete value.

Here's an example of the issue happening in my console before and after clicking on the value:

[image: Before and after clicking on the value]

Comment: I think that might be part of the closing quote of the string value.

Comment: It might be, but if you consider the length of that kind of IDs the first one has 28 chars and that one has 27. That's why i assume he is not seeing the whole value and what is missing is just one char.

Comment: Ah, that could be. A `startAt` instead of `equalTo` should work in that case.

Comment: Thank you both! I skipped fixing it for a bit and changed the structure of checkins to be a bit more flexible and the issue didn't arise again so that must have been it.